# Openlayers overlay on top of custom buttons

Tags: openlayers

So I have an openlayers map, which has a couple of custom buttons that are absolutely positioned in the top right corner.  I also have an openlayers Overlay that appears when clicking on some points in the map.  I want the Overlay to always appear on top of my buttons.  But the buttons always appear on top.  Code is something like this:

```
<div id="map">
   <button /> <----button that is absolutely positioned 
   <div id="popup">
</div>
```

I create an Overlay and reference my popup div.  Everything works fine with the overlay, except I want it on top of the other dom elements that are children of my map div.

The style on the ol-overlay-container-stopevent is z-index: 0.  In the dev tools if I update the z-index to 1 then my popup appears on top of my buttons like I would like.  Maybe the solution is to add in custom styles for this container, but is there any way to do this other than trying to override the css?

Answer (score 0):

It appears what I need to do is create an ol Control class and reference my button in the element argrument.  Then I add that to the map and it gets added inside of the viewport.  I then specify insertFirst: false on the popup Overlay and it now will appear on top of my buttons.